# Получение переменной и использование в функции

Tags: ajax, javascript

Доброго времени суток.
Есть форма, форма передает следующие параметры:

```
<form method="POST" action="/stat_post/" class="svodres">
```

В ajax делаю:

```
$(function(){
// получаем атрибут class
    var m_result = $(this).attr('class');

    $(m_result).submit(function(e){
 //...................

  });

});
```

но получается так, что в функцию он помещает

```
$('svodres').submit(function(e){ ....
```

а мне нужно

```
$('.svodres').submit(function(e){ ....
```

Как добавить точку в функции? :)

Я очень извиняюсь, если вопрос тупой, только учусь)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А почему вы записываете класс в переменную `m_class`, а событие ставите на `m_result`? И чем у вас в данной ситуации является `$(this)`?

А вообще, используйте конкатенацию:

```
$('.' + m_result)
```

Comment: @andreyqin да, прошу прощения, пока клепал для примера, не туда вписал.

Спасибо за ответ! Теперь понятно)

Comment: @Александр Маслов, пожалуйста. Вообще странно, что вы используете jQuery и не знаете, как склеиваются строки...